# Only first when expression works in apache camel choice?

Tags: regex, apache-camel

I have this route which check if body begins with "01" or "02" and calls different beans based on that. the problem is that only first one works. for example if I send a message beginning with "01" 
it works fine but if my message begins with "02" the otherwise part gets executed and i get the error message with an empty body.

```
<route id="genericService">
        <from uri="servlet:///genericService"/>
        <choice>
            <when>
                <simple>${body} regex "^01.*$"</simple>
                <bean ref="cardFacade" method="getBalance" />
            </when>
            <when>
                <simple>${body} regex "^02.*$"</simple>
                <bean ref="depositFacade" method="getBalance" />
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <transform>
                    <simple>error:  ${body}</simple>
                </transform>
            </otherwise>
        </choice>
        <marshal>
            <json />
        </marshal>
        <transform>
            <simple>${body}</simple>
        </transform>
    </route>
```

Comment: Are you sure the message begins with `02`... and there is no leading white space?

Comment: yes i am sure there is absolutely no leading characters. the most amazing part is that if i switch when statements the first one works fine.

Comment: I've no idea but the ChoiceProcessor doesn't look too hard to debug if you want to dig into the Camel code itself.

Comment: What happens if you add some log statements on the lines directly after `regex`. And, thinking about it more, can you please try this: add a log statement right after the `servlet:` call which logs both `${body}` and `${body.class.name}`. If it's not a `java.lang.String` then regex would fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the servlet component provides the body as a stream that is only readable once. So you need to either enable stream caching, or convert the message body to a non stream type such as String or byte[].

You can find more details here

- http://camel.apache.org/why-is-my-message-body-empty.html

And also see the 1st box on this page

- http://camel.apache.org/servlet

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in Java DSL (not the compilation issue). What I have to do is add .endchoice() for each and every choice some thing as below:

```
from(endPointTopic)
.errorHandler(deadLetterChannel)
.log("Message from Topic is ${body} & header string is ${header.Action}" )          
.choice()
    .when(header("Action").isEqualTo("POST"))
        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("POST"))
        .setHeader("Content-Type", constant("application/json"))
        .convertBodyTo(String.class)
        .to("log:like-to-see-all?level=INFO&showAll=true&multiline=true")
        .to(privateApi)
        .log("POST request for " + topicName)
        .endChoice()
    .when(header("Action").isEqualTo("PUT"))
        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("PUT"))
        .setHeader("Content-Type", constant("application/json"))
        .convertBodyTo(String.class)
        .to("log:like-to-see-all?level=INFO&showAll=true&multiline=true")
        .to(privateApi)
        .log("PUT request for " + topicName)
        .endChoice()
    .when(header("Action").isEqualTo("DELETE"))
        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("DELETE"))
        .setHeader("Content-Type", constant("application/json"))
        .convertBodyTo(String.class)
        .to("log:like-to-see-all?level=INFO&showAll=true&multiline=true")
        .to(privateApi)
        .log("DELET request for " + topicName)
        .endChoice()
    .otherwise()
        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("GET"))
        .setHeader("Content-Type", constant("application/json"))
        .convertBodyTo(String.class)
        .to("log:like-to-see-all?level=INFO&showAll=true&multiline=true")
        .to(privateApi)
        .log("Un-known HTTP action so posting to GET queue")
        .endChoice();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add .choice() .end() some thing as below:

```
 .choice()
   .when(header("Action").isEqualTo("POST"))
   
   .endChoice()
.end()
.choice()
   .when(header("Action").isEqualTo("PUT"))
  
   .endChoice()
.end()
```